# how do I scroll up in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac

I am used to windows having arrows on a constantly visible scrollbar.  On Mac the scrollbar is invisible.  I have to click in the vicinity, then use the up down arrow keys.  This is not only annoying but simply does not allow you to scroll in the terminal window.

Comment: 99.999% of the time (on Windows and on Mac) I use the scroll wheel. (Well, on a Mac it's not really a wheel but you do the same action). And if I ever need to a massive scroll that will take too long with the wheel, that's when I do the dance of getting the scroll bar to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two fingers on the trackpad. Dependent on settings, move them up to scroll down or move them down to scroll up

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apple magic mouse, the scroll wheel is invisible.  Just use your finger where the wheel "should" be and it will scroll.  Same goes for the Magic trackpad, 2 finger swipe up/down/left/right.

One thing of note, Apple changed the scroll direction in OS X (cant remember which version.  They call it "Natural Scrolling," which is anything but.  I use Windows at home and Macs at work and I had to turn off natural scrolling to make it actually be "natural."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the options to use a scroll wheel or two-finger swipe to scroll, you can bring back the scroll bar in System Preferences -> General pane -> Set "Show scroll bars:" to "Always".